# Special effects doesn't work in jssor slider in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jssor

I have downloaded jssor code for applying special effects on my slider. It works like a charm when I run it from Visual Studio 2013 also when I deployed it on IIS of same machine where Visual Studio installed.

But when I deploy it on different server and when I execute the website, everything works except the special effects. I am using Internet Explorer 11 but still I don't know why the slider doesn't adapt special effects while changing the image. It's just simply slide without any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.. I have just added

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

in head tag of my web page and its started working..